# How can I access the html nodes of 'hidden' class with R language as I'm unable to extract certain text associated with that node

Tags: java, html, r

Input:
read_fasta_html<-AMPs%>%html_nodes("pre")%>%html_text()
read_fasta_html

Output:

> read_fasta_html<-AMPs%>%html_nodes("pre")%>%html_text()
> read_fasta_html
> character(0)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example with link and expected output.

Comment: Actually I want to scrape fasta sequence present on this page link "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/TII12583.1?report=fasta". and i m getting character(0) if i am trying to extract text sequence through its html node "pre"

Comment: >TII12583.1 GhoT/OrtT family toxin [Enterococcus faecium]
MYLVRNAISFFITYFLSHDTMALVL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the sequence is using the `API` from which the webpage gets its text. The API can be found from `Fetch/XHR`tab on clicking `inspect` element.

[image]

```
'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=1626603948&db=protein&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000' %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_text2()
[1] ">TII12583.1 GhoT/OrtT family toxin [Enterococcus faecium] MYLVRNAISFFITYFLSHDTMALVL"
```

You can also further look into packages `rentrez` and `biomartr`

Comment: I want your help regarding that API you used for retreiving that fasta sequence like how you get that API from that specific url I mentioned above. It would be of great help for me.Thanks in advance @Nad Pat

Comment: I have added info in the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it helped me a lot.Thank you so much but I want to fetch this API directly with some R code . Is it possible with some libraries maybe?

Comment: Maybe you can study packages `rentrez` and `rentrez `. Maybe they can help you fetch the sequence directly.

Comment: Or else you need to use `RSelenium` to extract the sequence